# mysql - insert in two tables using autogenerate key from first insert table without using LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to insert some values into two different tables, this tables need to be linked, let's supposed I have:

- table product

  - id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  - name TEXT NOT NULL
- table ingredients

  - id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  - productID  INT NOT NULL
  - value TEXT NOT NULL

so I need to insert in a commit both tables but table ingredients needs to be linked the productID autogenerated by product table, I DON'T want to use LAST_INSERT_ID because I'm inserting multiples rows at the same time and I may get and id from other row.

Comment: "...because I'm inserting multiples rows at the same time..." -- Are you running a single SQL statement that inserts many rows, or multiple SQL inserts? If the latter, you can use LAST_INSERT_ID.

Comment: @TheImpaler no, I'm using a concurrent/parallel script which saves data individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` since is multi-thread safe. [MySQL's docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html) say:

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another client.

Comment: what if I'm using a conection pool?, conection pooll will reuse the conection, then it may get another id

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias A connection pool shouldn't disconnect other processes while they're using the connection.